# How to Stop getting System.TypeInitializationException everytime I use My stack class

Tags: c#, .net

I got a coding exercise in an online C# course where I have to Design my own stack class.
The problem I keep encountering with this code is that it keeps giving me a System.TypeInitializationException for some reason. I have tried changing modifiers but nothing has worked. Any solutions?
Here is the following code:

```
public class Stack
{
    public static List<object> StackStorage = new List<object>();
    public static object LastElement = StackStorage[StackStorage.Count - 1];
    public static object FirstElement = StackStorage[0];


    public void Push(object obj)
    {
        if (StackStorage.Count - 1 >= 8)
        {
            StackStorage.Remove(LastElement);
            StackStorage.Insert(0, obj);
        }
        else
        {
            StackStorage.Add(obj);

        }

           //Add Logic in here to check whether or not the List count
           //Is Longer than 8. Remember that .Count gives you a value NOT
           //Zero based. If you want the index of a value you would have
           //To do ExampleList.Count - 1.


    }
    public object Pop()
    {
        StackStorage.Remove(LastElement);
        return LastElement;

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        StackStorage.Clear();


    }

    public int PrintCount()
    {

        return StackStorage.Count();


    }




}
   And the code I have in the main method:
Stack MyStack = new Stack();
        MyStack.Push(1);
        MyStack.Push(2);
        MyStack.Push(3);
        Console.WriteLine(MyStack.PrintCount());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Post the entire exception. Also: **read** the entire exception. It would give you a better idea of what's wrong than "maybe it's the modifiers".

Comment: Ok, look at your fourth line of code. What do you think the value of `StackStorage.Count - 1` will be? Is that a valid value for the length of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<object> StackStorage = new List<object>();
public static object LastElement = StackStorage[StackStorage.Count - 1];
public static object FirstElement = StackStorage[0];
```

are computed once on application start and since StackStorage.Count - 1 is -1 on application start it gives you that exception.

What you really need is to calculate them every time you need access them. For example:

```
public object GetLastElement(){
  if (StackStorage.Count > 0)
      return StackStorage[StackStorage.Count - 1];
  throw new Exception("Collection is empty");
}
//and so on
```

But I would not recommend to go this road, better approach would be:

- get rid of static (as you want stack underlying collection to belong to instance of class not to instace of running process)
- use indexes
- use generics

In that case your class would look like:

```
    public class Stack<T>
    {
        private const int MAX_SIZE = 8;

        private List<T> StackStorage = new List<T>();

        private void RemoveLast()
        {
            StackStorage.RemoveAt(StackStorage.Count - 1);
        }

        public void Push(T obj)
        {
            StackStorage.Insert(0, obj);

            if (StackStorage.Count > MAX_SIZE)
                RemoveLast();
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            if (StackStorage.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Stack is empty");

            T result = StackStorage[StackStorage.Count - 1];
            RemoveLast();

            return result;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            StackStorage.Clear();
        }

        public int Count => StackStorage.Count;
    }
```

And you can use it like:

```
    Stack<int> MyStack = new Stack<int>();
    MyStack.Push(1);
    MyStack.Push(2);
    MyStack.Push(3);
    Console.WriteLine(MyStack.Count);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to initialize `LastElement`, you're trying to set it to the final element of `StackStorage`, which, at the time, has zero elements, thus no elements, and no last element.

```
 StackStorage.Count - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1 // invalid array index
```

Instead of using `FirstElement` and `LastElement`, just use the index you want when pushing and popping.

`FirstElement` and `LastElement` won't be the actual first and last elements anyway, since you're trying to initialize them at the start, instead of keeping them up to date as the `StackStorage` changes.